# plotting sub_plots from pivot_table using matplotlib/seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a code from a dataframe

```
Y = df['label']
for col in categorical_cols:
    tab = pd.crosstab(df[col],Y)
    annot = x.div(x.sum(axis=1).astype('float64'),axis=0)
    annot.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True)
    plt.title('Distribution of %s'%col)
    plt.xlabel('%s'%col,size='x-large')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.legend()
```

How can I plot these using different subplots in a single `figure` because this loops prints the last column's figure. So all figures are same.

Also: How can I produce the same using matplotlib/seaborn using matplotlib which shows me the % or absolute values.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the approach in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the different subplots and then pass one `axes` object to each call of `annot.plot` via the `ax` keyword, something like this:

```py
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = len(categorical_cols)
nrows = math.ceil(float(n) / 3.0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=nrows, figsize=(9, nrows*3))
ax = ax.flatten()

Y = df['label']
for idx, col in enumerate(categorical_cols):
    tab = pd.crosstab(df[col],Y)
    annot = x.div(x.sum(axis=1).astype('float64'),axis=0)
    annot.plot(kind='bar',stacked=True, ax=ax[idx])
    ax[idx].title('Distribution of %s'%col)
    ax[idx].set_xlabel('%s'%col,size='x-large')
    ax.tick_params('x', labelrotation=45)
    plt.legend()
```

Comment: sure! thank you. it was helpful but needed a second look as it was  in depth